# Use Log4j with jetty-maven-plugin 9.x

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9

How can I enable [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) for [jetty-maven-plugin 9](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html)?

I followed the [Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.6.v20130930/example-logging-log4j.html) for standalone Jetty 9 and added JARs and property file.

Jetty configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/mywebapp</contextPath>
            <jettyEnvXml>jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
        </webApp>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>log4j.configuration</name>
                <value>log4j-jetty.properties</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Spring inside my webb app logs with Log4j, but Jetty still logs with the wrong logger.

Console output:

```
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.0.5.v20130815:run (default-cli) @ mywebapp ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: mywebapp
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Defaulting to D:\projekte\test\workspace\test-parent\mywebapp\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = D:\projekte\test\workspace\test-parent\mywebapp\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /mywebapp
[INFO] Tmp directory = D:\projekte\test\workspace\test-parent\mywebapp\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/D:/projekte/test/workspace/test-parent/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = D:\projekte\test\workspace\test-parent\mywebapp\src\main\webapp
[INFO] jetty-9.0.5.v20130815
[INFO] No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
[INFO] No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[INFO] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
<14:03:42,507> <INFO > <ContextLoader> (main) - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
<14:03:42,562> <INFO > <XmlWebApplicationContext> (main) - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 25 14:03:42 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
<14:03:42,587> <INFO > <XmlBeanDefinitionReader> (main) - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]
<14:03:42,694> <INFO > <XmlBeanDefinitionReader> (main) - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf.xml]
<14:03:42,919> <INFO > <AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor> (main) - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[INFO] Setting the server's publish address to be /test
<14:03:43,231> <INFO > <ContextLoader> (main) - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 724 ms
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@224f70d3{/mywebapp,file:/D:/projekte/test/workspace/test-parent/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/D:/projekte/test/workspace/test-parent/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/}
[WARNING] !RequestLog
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@5a88a0f2{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

My Log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
log4j.debug=false

# console logger
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=<%d{ABSOLUTE}> <%-5p> <%c{1}> (%t) - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to set the location of the log properties in the `pom.xml`, it has to be a command line argument, see [Setting System Properties](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#setting-system-properties):

> However, **sometimes it is not possible to use this feature to set System properties** - sometimes the software component using the System property is already initialized by the time that maven runs (in which case you will need to provide the System property on the command line), or by the time that Jetty runs.

Changed command line:

```
mvn -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///D:/log4j-jetty.properties jetty:run
```

works with Maven 3.0.

But it doesn't work with Maven 3.1, because Maven 3.1 contains SLF4J [`SimpleLogger`](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html), see [Maven 3.1.x logging](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html):

> The standard Maven distribution, from Maven 3.1.0 onward, uses the SLF4J API for logging combined with the SLF4J Simple implementation

and Jetty uses SLF4J Simple implementation for its own logs (not for web application logs) instead of Log4j implementation.